# Python - using Regex findall strings after some fixed text

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm new to Python and am getting confused. I have a list of email strings and want to get the string after some specific text and before some text. So from the list below;

```
Email: promo@madeup.com
Email: dave@madeup.com
Email: john@madeup.com
```

get the following;

```
promo@madeup
dave@madeup
john@madeup
```

I've managed to get the first string (below) but can't seem to get all of them

```
import re

lines = '''
Email: promo@madeup.com
Email: dave@madeup.com
Email: john@madeup.com
'''


emailAddr = lines.split('Email:')[1] #start
emailAddr2 = emailAddr.split('.com')[0] #end
print(emailAddr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookbehind to match the `Email:` prefix before each email and the `.com` suffix.

```
emails = re.findall(r'(?<=Email: ).*(?=\.com)', lines)
print(emails)
```

Or just loop through the lines and remove the `Email:` prefix.

```
emails = [s.replace('Email: ', '').replace('.com') for s in lines.splitlines() if s]
print(emails)
```

Comment: Since parsing emails with regex is notoriously hard (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression), I like your second example :-)

Comment: Neither of my solutions does any real parsing. It assumes this is a fixed format file. It also only works for `.com` domains, it doesn't generalize.

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = '''
Email: promo@madeup.com
Email: dave@madeup.com
Email: john@madeup.com
'''

lines = lines.split('\n')
output = [x.split('Email:')[1].replace('.com','').strip() for x in lines if 'Email:' in x]
print(output)
```

will output:

```
['promo@madeup', 'dave@madeup', 'john@madeup']
```

if you want them all printed on a new line:

```
print('\n'.join(output))
```

will output:

```
promo@madeup
dave@madeup
john@madeup
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob that works! I've change dit slightly to lines = lines.split('\n')
output = [x.split('Email:')[1].split('.com')[0] for x in lines if 'Email:' in x]
print(output)

Comment: hi Ken, good to hear, upvote answers you felt were useful and accept the best one :)